# Prove that Fr$_{Y} (A) = Y \cap ($Fr$ (A))$ if Fr$(Y)\cap\text{Cl}(A) = \emptyset ($Fr$(A)$ and Fr$(Y)$ are boundaries of $A$ and $Y$ in $X$).

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ topological space, $\DeclareMathOperator{\Fr}{Fr}$
$ Y \subseteq X $ its subspace and $ A \subseteq Y $. Let $ \Fr_{Y} (A)$ be boundary of set $A$ in subspace $Y$. Prove that $ \Fr_{Y} (A) = Y \cap (\Fr (A) )$ if $ \Fr(Y) \cap \operatorname{Cl}(A) = \emptyset$   (where $\Fr(A) $ and $ \Fr(Y)$ are boundaries of $A$ and $Y$ in $X$).

P.S. definition of boundary: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)

I don't even know what strategy to use for solving this. I tried proving it directly but I got stuck right at the beggining. Any hint helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints to get you going:

1. A point $y \in Y$ belongs to $\newcommand{\Fr}{\mathrm{Fr}}\Fr_Y(A)$ if and only if every neighborhood of $y$ contains at least one point of $Y \cap A$ and at least one point of $Y \setminus A$. In particular, if $y \in \Fr_Y(A)$ then every neighborhood of $y$ contains both points of $A$ and $X \setminus A$, placing $y \in \Fr(A)$.
2. If $\Fr(Y) \cap \overline A = \emptyset$, then any points $y \in \overline A$ does not belong to $\Fr(Y)$. In particular, if $y \in Y \cap \Fr(A)$ then $y$ has a neighborhood containing *no* points of $X \setminus Y$. This implies $y$ is an interior point of $Y$.